# BCP creating csv in remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

When trying to execute bcp on a remote server, the csv file is created in the server's desktop instead of mine. Is there a way to tell bcp to create the csv file in my machine?

I use the following command:

```
declare @str varchar(4000)
set @str = 'bcp "select * from ##t_global" '
+ 'queryout "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\results.csv" -c -t, -S"Server" -T -C ACP'
exec xp_cmdshell @str
```

Comment: You need to tell the server the UNC path to your desktop (and a windows user that can access it). That means giving visibility for the server to your machine, which might be a security problem.

Comment: Personally, I would run `bcp` on your host and use a pull method, rather than push the data from SQL Server to your PC using both `xp_cmdshell` and `bcp`.

Comment: I am not certain this is still the case, but SQL Server could only write/read files locally ( although there are some hacks that I wouldn't recommend ). I would go with @Larnu's suggestion and run the BCP command on the machine that needs the file if possible.